# Zariski tangent space of parabola

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k=\overline{k}$ and $X=V(y-x^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2_k$ be a parabola. I would like to compute the Zariski tangent space of $X$ at $0$ directly from the definition $$T_0X=(\mathfrak{m}_{X,o}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,o}^2)^{\ast}.$$

I am stuck computing $\mathfrak{m}_{X,o}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,o}^2$ and its dual. I think $\mathfrak{m}_{X,o}=\{f\in \mathcal{O}_{X,0}|f(0)=0\}$ and $\mathfrak{m}_{X,o}^2=\{fg|f,g\in \mathcal{O}_{X,0}, f(0)=g(0)=0\}$, but what is the quotient?

I computed the tangent space using the Jacobian matrix to be the $x$-axis (as in the answer given here: [Zariski tangent space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518914/zariski-tangent-space)), but I would like to compute it using the abstract definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To abstractly do this, consider the coordinate ring of this variety, namely $A=k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ and localize at the ideal of the point where you want the tangent space, i.e $p=(x,y)$ and denote it $A_p$. We will abuse notation and use the symbols $x,y$ to denote the images of $x$ and $y$ in the quotient $k[x,y]\to k[x,y]/(y-x^2) $ and just remember the relation $y=x^2$.

Now we are trying to compute the cotangent space at $(0,0)$ which as you note is $m_{A_p}/m_{A_p}^2$. Now the unique maximal ideal of $A_p$ is $(x,y)=(x,x^2)=(x)$. So we see that $m_{A_p}/m_{A_p}^2$ is $(x)/(x^2)$ which is a one dimensional $k$-vector space.